# Implement MongoDB aggregation pipeline with $group stage in java spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to implement a MongoDB query in java using Spring mongo.

This is the native MongoDB query:

```js
db.ShieldReport.aggregate([
    {$match:{"sellerCode":"e1aaf3"}}, 
    {$project:{bucketName:"$bucketName", brandName: "$brandName", createdTime : "$createdTime", sellerCode : "$sellerCode"}}, 
    {$sort:{"createdTime":-1}},
    {$group: 
            {
                _id: { sellerCode: "$sellerCode", bucketName: "$bucketName", brandName: "$brandName"}, 
                itemsSold: { $first: { bucketName: "$bucketName", brandName: "$brandName", createdTime : "$createdTime"} }
            } 

    },
    {$sort:{"itemsSold.createdTime":-1}},
    {$project : { _id : "$_id.sellerCode", bucketName :"$itemsSold.bucketName", brandName : "$itemsSold.brandName"}}
])
```

In my Spring java version, I have got it this far:

```java
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("sellerCode").is(filterR‌​equest.getSellerCode‌​())),
    Aggregation.project("bucketName")
               .andInclude("brandName")
               .an‌​dInclude("createdTim‌​e")
               .andInclude("sell‌​erCode"), 
    sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdTime"), 
    group("sellerCode", "brandName", "bucketName")
);
```

But the problem is I am not able to create the `itemSold` field. How do I create that?

Comment: I tried using 
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("sellerCode").is(filterRequest.getSellerCode())),
       Aggregation.project("bucketName").andInclude("brandName").andInclude("createdTime").andInclude("sellerCode"),
       sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdTime"),
       group("sellerCode", "brandName", "bucketName"));

But the problem is I am not able to create the itemSold field. How do I create that?

Comment: I have restructured your question a little to make it more understandable. I have stated the main question at the top, added syntax hints for the json query and the java code, and made some other rewording changes too. If you have further clarification you could add, please [edit] the question to improve it further; edits are encouraged on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could restructure your pipeline in Spring as follows:

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation( 
    Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("sellerCode").is(filterR‌​equest.getSellerCode‌​())),
    Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdTime"), 
    Aggregation.group("sellerCode", "bucketName", "brandName") 
        .first("bucketName").as("bucketName")
        .first("brandName").as("brandName")
        .first("createdTime ").as("createdTime "),
    Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdTime"),
    Aggregation.project("bucketName", "brandName")
        .and("sellerCode").previousOperation()             
);
```

As you can see some of the pipeline stages have been omitted because they are really not necessary. For instance, the `$project` pipeline before the `$group` step can be taken off since the `$group` pipeline operator will apply the accumulators

In the group step, you group the intermediate filtered documents by the three fields and store the other field values in new fields aided by the `$first` operator.

Sort the intermediate result by the `createdTime` field reference of the previous group operation.

Finally in the fourth step, select the "bucketName" and "brandName" fields from the previous group operation. Note that "sellerCode" again implicitly references an group-id field.

Comment: the fields() method inside the group method is throwing compile time error.

Comment: @Nayanava Try the updated method again and let me know how that goes.